# Why do enzyme not find 'tr' in a table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm writting some test using `enzyme` but I have some weird behavior. Here is my test :

```
  import React from 'react'
  import { TypeTable } from 'routes/Type/components/TypeTable'
  import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
  import { Table } from 'react-toolbox'

  // ...

  let _props, _wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    _props = {
      getTypes: sinon.spy(),
      types: [
        { name: 'type 1'},
        { name: 'type 2'}
      ]
    }
    _wrapper = shallow(<TypeTable {..._props} />)
  })

  it('Should render a <Table>', () => {
    expect(_wrapper.is(Table)).to.be.true
  })

  it('should render 2 rows', () => {
    expect(_wrapper.find('tbody').find('tr')).to.have.length(2)
  })
```

The first test is working. The second one is not working (the assertion is failing : `expected { Object (root, unrendered, ...) } to have a length of 2 but got 0`)

But in my second test, if I print the content of my `_wrapper` using `console.log(_wrapper.html())` I get

```
'<table data-react-toolbox="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-react-toolbox-table="row">
      <td>type 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-react-toolbox-table="row">
      <td>type 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'
```

Which seems to be ok and which contains several `tr`.

Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shallow` will not "render" subcomponents. It is used to test a single component and not its children. I think that using `mount` instead of shallow will let you test what you want.

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.

Comment: Ok, but is it normal that `_wrapper.html()` returns me the correct html ?

Comment: Yes. The difference between shallow and mount is a bit confusing sometimes. When I have a problem I usually check / switch between them. 
For example I usually use mount when I want to test how props are passed to children components instead of the actual output.